# Zend Framework - No error 404

Tags: zend-framework, http-status-code-404, zend-auth

I'm tearing my hair with a site developed by ZF. I have to try to make changes on it while it was developed by offshore companies ...

Currently, if I go on the site: http://www.riads-marrakech.org/

If I http://www.riads-marrakech.org/sgfdgdfgdg => no error, just the main content layout that displays "auth" instead of a 404

I already can not generate different urls for multilingual content (see: [Zend Framework Multilingual route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10336893/zend-framwork-multilingual-route))

I guess this error is relayed by Zend_Auth. This site uses a config file acl.ini:

```
[roles]
guest = null
planificateur = null
administrateur = null
webmaster = null
Standard = null

[ressources]
index = null
error = null
inscription = null
inscriptionnewsletter = null
utilisateur = null
search = null
apropos = null
ficheriad = null
admin_index = null
admin_users = null
admin_agendas = null
renseignement = null
agenda = null
loisir = null
admin_config = null
admin_usersprofile = null
admin_typemisenavant = null
admin_misenavant = null
admin_misenavantautres = null
admin_misenavantbonplan = null
admin_misenavantoffrespeciale = null
admin_etablissement = null
admin_prestation = null
admin_lieutouristique = null
admin_exclusivite = null
admin_chambre = null
admin_prixetablissement = null
admin_prixchambre = null
admin_pack = null
admin_compositionpack = null
admin_newsletter = null
admin_statistique = null
language = null

[planificateur]
allow.admin_index = deconnect
allow.error = null
allow.index = null
allow.inscription = null
allow.search = null
allow.admin_agendas = null
allow.language = null

[and the same for each role]
```

My HTACCESS :

```
ErrorDocument  404  /404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)|$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Anyone can help me, please T_T ?

Comment: Something is relaying everything to auth... what's in the 404.php file?

Comment: Sounds like expected behavior to me. The site is requiring authentication prior to dispatch of all requests, and why is that so bad?

Comment: Ah, yes. I see what is happening. Access to the 404 page is being mediated by auth.

Comment: My 404 file is... empty. http://www.riads-marrakech.org/404.php just display 'test' actually.

Comment: Whatever is requiring all requests to be authenticated needs modification, please post the code to that part of the application. It's possibly in a controller plugin (application/plugins)

Comment: is it [ressources] or [resources] ?

Comment: it's [ressources], it's a french website and ... I think it's just a term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the problem.

There is a plugin Auth which test and redirect... I just change the routine and it's good ^^